# PHP FFI - Convert void* to int

Tags: php, c++, ffi

I have a C++ function, it casts int to void*.

```
void* get() {
  int a = 555;
  return (void*)a;
}
```

In my PHP code, I call this C++ function and want to convert its return value to int.

```
$ffi = FFI::cdef(
  "void* get();",
  "dllpath");

$voidptr = $ffi->get();

// convert void* to int
```

FFI::cast("int", $voidptr) does not work.
The only successful method I tried was to print the $voidptr through print_r($voidptr, true);, and then get the int value through regular matching. Is there any other better way?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you return value this very weird way?

Comment: ```a``` is a local variable to function ```get()``` and returning its address will be resulted into the ```undefined behavior```.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh he s not returning the address only the **value** converted to the pointer. There is no `&`

Comment: @gulpr Thanks. That's true. I thought it is supposed to return the address of the variable.

Comment: Just rewrite the "C" function to return an int. All the other stuff is just confusing

Comment: C++ does not require that `void*` is large enough to hold all the bits in an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 methods:

1. Declare the return value as int:

   ```
   $ffi = FFI::cdef(
          "int get();",
          "dllpath");
   $intval = $ffi->get();
   ```
2. Create a nullptr and subtract it:

   ```
   $nullptr = $ffi->cast('void*', 0);
   $intval = $voidptr - $nullptr;
   ```